# Deploy in multiple environment (DEV, UAT, PROD) in Jenkins

Tags: python, jenkins

I have a Python app , I want to deploy it first in DEV, then in UAT and finally on PROD. I could build it using Jenkins with Webhooks so that when It's pushed to DEV it triggers a build(It runs the nosetests suit). I want this app to be promoted in UAT and PROD subsequently if build in DEV and UAT passes respectively. I don't want any manual intervention. Can it be done with Jenkins and how? If not what could be the best alternative??

P.S
I thought of doing remote login on my DEV, UAT, PROD servers from my Jenkins server. and triggering the build but I am still unclear how to do it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Best practice would be to use [Jenkins pipeline](https://jenkins.io/pipeline/getting-started-pipelines/). You could necessitate progression between your environments by using [input step](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-input-step/) and have your (I presume) asynchronous deployment trigger the continuation of the pipeline to the next stage (environment)

Comment: With input step, the user needs to respond to the prompt. Can this be automated?

Answer (score 5):

One option is to add your UAT and PROD remote environments as Jenkins slaves.
[Check this documentation for more on that](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Distributed+builds)

When adding a new node you could set an expression label for each environment you add as slave such as: `remote_uat`. You could then use the **Restrict where this project can be run** option in your job definition and reference that label that you have defined previously. This will tell jenkins to build that job only in remote nodes that have that label expression assigned to it.

Ta enable jenkinst to trigger UAT and PROD related builds after a successful DEV build you should use [Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin), this will enable you to configure your job to trigger other jobs on post-execution steps.

Comment: Unfortunately, links are broken